# How to read TableViewCell Delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to read this methods and understand it.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

&

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: what? what do you mean how to read? basically the first one says number of rows in section, second is cell for row at index path.

Comment: i mean what is (NSInteger)tableView: and (UITableView *) means.

Comment: Check this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_tableview.htm

Comment: so the method requires you to return 1. NSInteger, 2, a uitableviewCell instance.

Comment: (UITableView *) what this "*" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

 - Means that the method is a instance method VS `+(NSInteger)something` which is a class method. The + and - mean different things like explained.

`NSInteger` - the return value which is a Integer. NS is a apple class prefix.

tableView is the method name. If you type `tableView` in your `ViewController` which has a `UITableview` you will get all delegate methods. 

(UITableView *)tableView is the first argument of the method. tableView is a pointer which helps you access your UITableView object in memory.

numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section is the second argument.

; Means that it is a method declaration vs a method definition.
```

Comment: Yw, never stop learning ;). Awesome iOS tuts page - https://www.raywenderlich.com/

Answer (score 0):

Every func have a return type thats means what actually this function return so you have to use `return` keyword to accomplish this.

1. `numberOfRowsInSection` returns `Integer`

   - how many rows your table have.
2. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns `UItableViewCell`

   - One row of your tableview which is reusable by the dequeue property of tableViewCell.